# Rails - nested model input data not appearing in "show" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am having trouble figuring out how to make some data collected through a nested model appear on the "show" page. I have a rails app with 3 models, a User model, a Project model, and a Team model. The model associations are as follows:

Project:-

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, :through => :team
  has_one :team, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :team, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Team:-

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :project
    has_many :users

end
```

User:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams


end
```

Every project has one team, and every team consists of many users who are already saved in the database. What I would like to do exactly is to make it possible to select multiple existing users within the project form (through a nested form) and save them to a model called team. I managed to get the form working correctly, but im not sure how to go about saving the data collected to the team model, and then to make the group of users that were selected (the team) to appear in project's show page. Please help!

P.S I used the nested form gem to add multiple team members within the project's form.

Projects Show page:-

```
<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for(@project, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal)   do |f| %>


  <% f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %>
  <% if builder.object.new_record? %>

  <%= builder.collection_select :user, User.all, :id, :email, { prompt: "Please select", :selected => params[:user], label: "Employee" } %> 
  <% else %> 
  <%= builder.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove" %>

  <% end %>

<%= f.link_to_add "Add Team Member", :teams %>



 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

projects controller:-

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_with(@projects)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.pictures.build
    @project.teams.build
    respond_with(@project)
  end


  def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.pictures.build
  @project.teams.build
  end

  def create

    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created project."
    redirect_to @project
    else
    render :action => 'new'
    end

  end

  def update
    @project.update(project_params)
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  private
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:id, :title, :description, :status, :phase, :location, :image, pictures_attributes: [:id, :image], teams_attributes: [:project_id, :user_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want that `collection_select` to be displayed on `show page` then you need to remove the `<% if builder.object.new_record? %>` line and the corresponding `<% else %>` and `<% end %>`

Comment: this is unrelated to your answer, but I just tried to create a new project, and I am getting this error now: ArgumentError in ProjectsController#new .  No association found for name `teams'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: I did not previously anticipate this problem as I was only editing existing entries. Do u know what the problem could be?

Comment: I fixed the error I mentioned earlier, however I am still struggling with my initial problem. what is the code I need to write in order for the team input to appear in the show page? I tried your suggestion but its still not appearing.